# Can gitHeadInfo.gin be safely added to .gitignore (without interfering with gitinfo's proper functioning)?

Tags: revision-control, git, gitinfo

Can `gitHeadInfo.gin` be safely added to `.gitignore` *without* interfering with `gitinfo`'s proper functioning ?

I'm asking this, cuz currently (using `gitinfo`) `git`'s working directory is *never* clean: `# modified:   gitHeadInfo.gin` and this just seems a bit "untidy".

Comment: @Brent.Longborough

Comment: Could you elaborate more how this is related to LaTeX? I don't see a strong correlation with the site?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo ?

Comment: I agree, it was untidy. In the new replacement, `gitinfo2`, gitHeadInfo.gin now lives in the .git/ directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This perhaps depends a bit on your workflow, but I always exlude it from being tracked by git. For me this seems to work fine. I usually have some git hooks for updating the .gin file after a commit etc. Maybe not the most elegant way, but I do not see any problems.

Comment: In case anybody wonders how to remove `gitHeadInfo.gin` from `.gitignore`: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/2153622) or (equivalently) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7693316/2153622).